# Offline event payment

Tags: civievent, wordpress

I want to register offline payments of an event. 
The total cost of event is € 100. Contacts can pay twice. € 50 at the end of October and 50€ at the end of December. 
I want to send the email notification to remind payments. 
When i put a partecipiant registration to the event, I can select the payment status. 
If you register a second payment instead I can not select the payment status. Why ?

Thanks.
Marco

Comment: Help, please. Why i can't change Status of payment ?

Answer (score 2):

The 'Contribution status' is automatically updated when the second payment is added. For example:

- Register a participant for an event that costs $800
- Log the contribution as $400 and save the registration
- Note that the contribution is 'Partially paid' in the registration list
- View the participant record, click on 'Add payment'
- Add a payment of $400
- Note that the contribution status has been updated to 'Completed'

If you want to manually change the status of the entire contribution, you can do so by editing the contribution.

If you want to change the status of individual payments then that looks like a feature request! It doesn't appear to be possible to even edit individual payments at the moment.